# How do I pipe output from sed -n into xargs?

Tags: sed, grep, xargs

I need help piping some `sed` output to `xargs`. This is not working, nothing is being echoed:

`fswatch -xr mysitedir | sed -n '/Updated$/p' | xargs -L1 -I {} echo {}`

My end goal here is not actually to `echo`, but to trigger my build tool (`soupault`) whenever `fswatch` detects changes in my site directory. The `sed` command is basically interchangeable with `grep` in my case. It simply filters this stream of events:

```
$ fswatch -xr site
/home/jplew/Sites/projects/soupault/site IsDir
/home/jplew/Sites/projects/soupault/site PlatformSpecific
/home/jplew/Sites/projects/soupault/site IsDir
/home/jplew/Sites/projects/soupault/site/blog/index.html Updated
/home/jplew/Sites/projects/soupault/site/blog PlatformSpecific
/home/jplew/Sites/projects/soupault/site/blog IsDir
/home/jplew/Sites/projects/soupault/site/blog/index.html Updated
/home/jplew/Sites/projects/soupault/site/blog PlatformSpecific
/home/jplew/Sites/projects/soupault/site IsDir
/home/jplew/Sites/projects/soupault/site PlatformSpecific
/home/jplew/Sites/projects/soupault/site IsDir
/home/jplew/Sites/projects/soupault/site/blog/index.html Updated
```

Down to this:

```bsh
$ fswatch -xr site | sed -n '/Updated$/p' 
/home/jplew/Sites/projects/soupault/site/blog/index.html Updated
/home/jplew/Sites/projects/soupault/site/blog/index.html Updated
/home/jplew/Sites/projects/soupault/site/blog/index.html Updated
```

Why isn't `xargs` printing anything?

Comment: You don't actually need to use sed here.  fswatch can filter events by itself.  There's even an example very similar to what you want in the man page: `fswatch --event Updated path/to/directory | xargs -n 1 bash_command`.    Just add `-0 --event Updated` to  your fswatch command and `-0 -r` to xargs, and you should be good to go.

Comment: oh wow, I completely missed that option, thanks so much. Not the answer to my question but the solution to my problem. :)

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23030127/1011766

Because `fswatch` is a long-running process, I had to use sed's `-u` flag to unbuffer the stream.

```
-u, --unbuffered

       load minimal amounts of data from the input files and flush the output buffers more often
```

This simple fix did it:

`fswatch -xr mysitedir | sed -un '/Updated$/p' | xargs -L1 -I {} echo {}`

---

### NOTE

Better solution from @cas for my specific use-case is to use `fswatch`'s built-in --event flag:

```
fswatch --event Updated -0r mysitedir | xargs -0r -I{} echo {}
```

Comment: Or `grep --line-buffered 'Updated$'` but you shouldn't use `xargs -I` without `-d`/`-0` (unless `fswatch` happens to write data in that very specific format which seems unlikely) nor `echo` here (and `-L1` is redundant). You'd also want to consider what would happen if a watched filename contains newline characters.

Comment: thanks for the tips! `fswatch` has a -0 flag which plays nice with `xargs` -0, but can you suggest how to get the `sed` command in between to recognize and pipe through the null character? This does not produce any output: `fswatch -0xr site templates soupault.conf | sed -n "/Updated\x0/p"`

Comment: @JPLew if it's GNU sed, it has a `-z` or `--null-data` option